# Add element to another child if parent does not contain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I check each `div.item` to see if it does **not** contain `span.premium` and then add a new span (let's call that `span.free`) to `div.screenshot`?

```html
<div id="video1" class="item">
  <div class="screenshot">
    <img src="image1.png" />
  </div>
  <h3>I am Video 1</h3>
</div>
<div id="video2" class="item">
  <div class="screenshot">
    <img src="image2.png" />
  </div>
  <h3>I am Video 2 <span class="premium">P</span></h3>
</div>
<div id="video3" class="item">
  <div class="screenshot">
    <img src="image3.png" />
  </div>
  <h3>I am Video 3</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your JS code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With one line of code:

```
$('div.item:not(:has(span.premium))').find('.screenshot').append('<span class="free">NEW SPAN</span>');
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/wxL2ujf8/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [:has()](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), [:not()](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), and [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) like

```
$('div.item:not(:has(span.premium))').each(function(){
    $('div.screenshot').append('<span class="free"></span>')
});
```